# C# Window form text box contents have been highlighted event

Tags: c#

is there an event for when the contents of a text box have been highlighted.

If not is there a way to determine this.

Also is there a way to determine of a text box has been tabbed to.

Thanks,

Comment: you want textbox Selection event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no event for highlighting.. but you can simulate it via the `MouseUp` and `KeyUp` events:

```
private void textBox_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (textBox.SelectedText != "")
        MessageBox.Show("Selected!");
}

private void textBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if (textBox.SelectedText != "")
        MessageBox.Show("Selected!");
}
```

There is also an `Enter` event for when the TextBox gains focus.

Comment: How do I determine use of shift key. Tab key still highlights contents when it reaches text box.

Comment: You don't.. you check for SelectedText each time there is a `KeyUp` which means it works for all combinations of keys @user2034477

Comment: I need to input a number like 65, 101 etc

Comment: The enter event works great. Only thing you can still highlight with shift and left arrow. If I can determine that the shift key has been pressed I can clear the contents

Comment: Yes, I see the ".SelectedText". I think this covers me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to mix a few events for this.

1. Capture Left Mouse button OR Shift Key+Arrow key
2. MouseDrag event also must be captured after that
3. Mouse Button Up too (for the next time).

Comment: How do I determine it is the shift key.

Comment: @user2034477 you dont, you check for SelectedText each time there is a `KeyUp`